# Reclaim space of pruned images docker WSL

Tags: docker, wsl2, vhd, vhdx

On my Windows 11 machine, I am running several containers formed from images that are updated regularly. I've connected the docker engine with WSL because that's where the images are built.

I noticed that the space on the hard disk that docker WSL uses doesn't shrink. Ever. Only a "purge data" command on docker desktop does seem to do the trick. But. This has a side benefit of removing all of my images and containers. Not that very nice.

If I run `docker image prune -a` unnecessary images are purged, but the space is not reclaimed:

```
ronald@Ronald:~/$ docker image prune -a
WARNING! This will remove all images without at least one container associated to them.
Are you sure you want to continue? [y/N] y
Deleted Images:
untagged: my.registry:somehash
deleted: sha256:somehash
...


Total reclaimed space: 0B
```

I've tried several solutions from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1606213/how-do-i-get-back-unused-disk-space-from-ubuntu-on-wsl2):

- Docker desktop restart. Does nothing.
- Shrinking the ext4.vhdx file with `diskpart` and `Optimize-vhd`. Also doesn't shrink it.

So question: How do I tell docker to remove unused images without having to remove the images that I am using?