# Reclaim WSL2 disk space after setting it to sparse

Tags: hard-drive, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, disk-image

Following the advice on [How do I get back unused disk space from Ubuntu on WSL2?](https://superuser.com/questions/1606213/how-do-i-get-back-unused-disk-space-from-ubuntu-on-wsl2) I set my WSL disk image to sparse with `wsl --manage <distro> --set-sparse true`. But the ext4.vhd file is still very large (~70 GB) while running `du` inside WSL reports only about 10 GB.

Will the disk size be reduced dynamically as I use my C:/ drive or do I have to manually reduce it? If I can, I'd like to force update the now sparse disk so that I know how much free space I actually have left on my drive.

Comment: Assuming you're linking *because* of the accepted answer, this part of the "older answer" still holds true: *shrinking it to reclaim unused space is something that must currently be done manually*.

Comment: This older method should work : "Exporting the WSL distro and re-importing it into a new WSL instance".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can revert the sparse mode, run the `optimize-vhd` command, and then set it back to sparse. something along this lines. not sure what's the implication of this, at least it works in my case.

1. Revert sparse mode

`wsl --manage <distro> --set-sparse false`

2. Optimize the disk

`optimize-vhd -Path <path-to-your-vhdx>.vhdx -Mode full`

3. Set it back to sparse mode

`wsl --manage <distro> --set-sparse true`