# How to allocate disk space from WSL2 to C: drive (Windows 10 Pro)

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, disk-space, wsl2

I've installed WSL2 on Windows 10 Pro.

I am not sure how I came up with that split between WSL and C:, but basically now my WSL seem to have a partition too big (250GB) for what is needed (~15GB), so I'm left with 235GB free on WSL while my C: drive is getting full (only ~6.7GB free) ...

I would like to reallocate some of the 250GB disk space allocated to WSL, back to my Windows C: drive.

Does anyone have a clean solution please?

Screenshot of my drives as they appear in "This PC":

[image: Screenshot of my drives as they appear in "This PC"]

Comment: [WSL absolutely is not using 250 GB](https://superuser.com/questions/1491270/how-much-disk-space-is-wsl-using-on-windows?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well here's the good news -- You didn't accidentally allocate 250G to WSL.  WSL2 allocates what is known as a "sparse" virtual disk.  That means that *internally*, it appears at it's maximum size (250GB in this case).  However, *externally* what is really being used is entirely different.  When empty, a sparse disk will actually take up 0 bytes on the host drive.

You can see an example of this from within WSL with the following:

```
> cd ~
> dd if=/dev/zero of=sparse_file bs=1 count=0 seek=512M
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 3.9604e-05 s, 0.0 kB/s
> ls -lhn sparse_file
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 512M Nov 25 19:10 sparse_file
> du sparse_file
0       sparse_file
> rm sparse_file
```

The file *appears* to be 512MB, but `du` (disk usage) shows that it really takes 0 on the disk.

So when you view the filesystem through the `\\WSL$\` network share, it's simply showing the maximum *possible* size to which the virtual WSL2 disk can grow.

You can see how much space the WSL2 virtual disk is *actually* taking by searching your drive for `ext4.vhdx`.  It will be in something like `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\<DistributionPackage>\LocalState`.  For Ubuntu, for instance, the "DistributionPackage" will be something like `CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc` (but will change depending on the release).

If the size of the virtual disk really *is* much larger than you expect, then this is likely because the sparse file will *grow* as space is used within the virtual disk, but it will not *shrink* when you remove files.

You can reclaim this space in several ways.  Please see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1612289/1210833) for details on that, if needed.

Well that's the good news.  The bad news is that (assuming it isn't WSL) you'll need to find what is *actually* taking up all that space on your Windows drive.  There are a few ways to do this.  You might start with the "Storage" settings in Windows, but you may need a [more detailed analysis](https://superuser.com/q/8248/1210833) as well.